# Is else{} necessary?

Tags: c++

Is it okay if I don't include else{ } every time I use if-else? or should I include it? C++!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x,sum=0,d=0;
    do{
        cout<<"Enter a number: ";
        cin>>x;
        if(x>0){
            sum+=x;
            d++;
        }
        else{}
    }while(x!=0);
    {
        cout<<"Sum: "<<sum<<endl;
        cout<<"Average: ";
        if(d==0){
            cout<<"0";
        }
        else{
            cout<<(float)sum/d;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's like asking "is a passenger-seat in my car necessary?"

Comment: `else{}` is not necessary.  It does nothing.

Comment: Having else block it not necessary. An if statement can be followed by an optional else statement, which executes when the boolean expression is false. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_if_else_statement.htm

Comment: It _can_ be required to disambiguate nested if-statements not enclosed in braces. But that's not happening in this program.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `else {}` could be useful? (I mean as a general rule, ignoring special cases.) Sure, if you don't include the `else {}` part, then you no longer have an `if-else` statement, so strictly speaking the `else {}` might be needed for you to use an `if-else`. However, in that case I would ask why are you so set on using `if-else` instead of `if`?

Comment: Related question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388241/does-an-empty-else-clause-have-any-significance-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388241/does-an-empty-else-clause-have-any-significance-in-c)

Comment: Despite all the "is not necessary" statements, there is one case where it could serve a purpose. This is when you nest `if` statements without braces: `if (A) if (B) doB(); else {} else notA();`. Here, if you remove the `else {}`, the meaning is changed completely: the `else notA();` no longer is the alternative branch of `if (A)`. That said, this case is usually corrected by using braces, not by inserting `else {}`.

Comment: Seen the comment of j6t, there is nothing opinion-based about this question, so I decided to re-open it.

Comment: It's not required by language rules. But there are code guidelines which require it, e.g. MISRA C. It's code standard unrelated to language itself, just a requirement for  code maintenance.

Comment: @j6t Code like that would never pass my code review. I would tell the coder to add braces and remove the empty "else"

Comment: @j6t It is not possible to use `else {}` in `if` statements without braces. Why? Because the instant you add `else {}`, you've added braces and no longer have "without braces". For the use you envision, you would have to use `else ;` (semicolon instead of braces for the empty branch). Or you could rephrase the situation as "`if` statements without braces except for empty statements".

Answer (score 0):

else is not required if it is not necessary, for example, you can write:

```
if(1)
    cout<<"hello world";
```

and this would work with no problem