# Keep empty else blocks on the same line as the else in clang format (and the same for if) but wrap braces after if and else for non empty blocks

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm trying to achieve the following clang formatings for if and else blocks:

1.For empty blocks, i'd like to keep them (single lined) on the same line as the end of the condition or right after the else, like

1.1

```
if (true) {}
else {}
```

1.2

```
if (true
    ) {}
else {}
```

1.3

```
  if (true


            ) {}


    else {}
```

2.Non-empty blocks should always be wrapped after the control statement and before and after the else

2.1

```
if (true)
{
    ;
}
else
{
    ;
}
```

2.2

```
if (true) {}
else
{
    ;
}
```

2.3

```
if (true)
{
    ;
}
else {}
```

2.4

```
if (true)
{
    // is this true
}
else
{
    /* this might be false */
}
```

3.**but never**

3.1.1

```
if (true) {
    ;
}
else {
    ;
}
```

3.1.2

```
if (true) {
    ;
} else {
    ;
}
```

3.1.3

```
if (true)
{
    ;
} else
{
    ;
}
```

3.1.4

```
if (true)
{
    ;
} else
{
    ;
}
```

3.2.1

```
if (true) {
}
else {
}
```

3.2.2

```
if (true) {
} else {
}
```

3.2.3

```
if (true)
{
} else
{
}
```

3.2.4

```
if (true)
{
} else
{
}
```

I'm not able to find a solution for the empty blocks.

Comment: Why are you writing empty blocks?

Comment: maybe enumerate your examples. I find it confusing to have so many so similar cases

Comment: @super Because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053371/what-is-the-benefit-of-terminating-if-else-if-constructs-with-an-else-clause (I'm aware that it's named misra-C and not misra-cpp but that's what ppl defined for our code base)

Comment: @idclev463035818 I don't understand what you mean by enumerate. I tried to describe in few words but gave example in case that those are not accurate enough since english is not my first or second language. Can you elaborate?

Comment: enumerate: "1. with `;`: 1.1 `first example` 1.2 `second example` 2. without `;` 2.1 ...." it was just a suggestion...

Comment: @idclev463035818 oh, ic. The question was really honest and it's a good idea. Thanks!